# Responsive Esri app: not sure how to collapse sidebar to button

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, mobile

Currently, I have a sidebar with text. How do I collapse it to a button when the screen size is below a certain pixel width? Here's the app on Code Pen: [Click for App](https://codepen.io/underjollyroger/pen/XWXPgqm).

This sample code does what I would like to do, but rather with a side bar. [Sample Code](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/view-breakpoints-css/index.html)

I plugged this in to the JS, but nothing happened:

```
if (newVal === "large"){
 // clear the view's default UI components if
 // app is used on a mobile device
 view.ui.components = [];
}
});
```

I plugged this in to the CSS to see if I can get the sidebar to go away when the screen is less than 992 pixels, but nothing happened. I'm not sure if you can even call the sidebar element?

```
.esri-view-width-less-than-large .sidebar {
    display: none;
}
```

I figured I'd try because it does work with the zoom button:

```
.esri-view-width-less-than-large .esri-zoom .esri-widget--button {
    display: none;
}
```

Here's an older thread that collapses a sidebar into a button. But I'm not using Bootstrap, or even sure if I should. [Bootstrap app](https://community.esri.com/thread/152782)

Answer (score 2):

You have some issues to resolve in order to achieve what you want.

The first thing is that `sidebar` is not using the ui provide by the library, you are positioning it by yourself. So, if you want to hide it, you also need to do it by yourself.

Using the `widthBreakpoint` of the view, you could do something like this,

```
view.watch("widthBreakpoint", function(newVal){
  console.log(newVal);
  if (newVal === "xsmall"){
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = 'none';
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('sidebar').style.display = 'block';
  }
});
```

That will hide `sidebar` when the width of the view is less than `xsmall` and show it in other case (btw, I think it is actually a side panel not side bar ;) ).

Comment: Thanks! That hid the sidebar. But, I still would like to know how I can have the sidebar text in a widget/button when the sidebar is hidden?

Comment: You want a button to open the sidebar that appears when sidebar hides?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I posted the sample code to illustrate what I'd like to do with the sidebar.